# Matching against the value of a Regex group containing an HTML entity

Tags: jmeter

I have the following element on an HTML page:

```
<option value="52">Engine&nbsp;Specialist</option>
```

I have a regular expression extractor giving me a variable named SpecialistInfo:

```
<option value="(\d+)">(.+?)<\/option>
```

JMeter gives me a match and I can access the matched values using the "group notation" syntax: SpecialistInfo_g1 and SpecialistInfo_g2

In a subsequent test I have a response assertion with a pattern of `${SpecialistInfo_g2}` and I'm tyring to match against the following: "This person is an Engine Specialist"

This understandably fails with an assertion error: `Assertion failure message:Test failed: text expected to contain /Engine&nbsp;Specialist/`

I have tried using a matching pattern of: `${__unescapeHtml(${SpecialistInfo_g2})}` which seems to replace the `&nbsp;` entity with a space but the match still fails.
The assertion error JMeter gives me is `Assertion failure message:Test failed: text expected to contain /Engine Specialist/`

Does anyone have suggestions on what to try?

Comment: No.  The Pattern Matching Rules is set to "contains" so it will match any occurrence of the pattern in the response text.  If it was set to "equals" then you would be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My expectation is that [__unescapeHtml() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__unescapeHtml) produces something weird and not the space and hence your assertion fails.

Try using the following [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) instead:

```
${__groovy(vars.get('SpecialistInfo_g2').replace('&nbsp;'\, '\u0020'),)}
```

This will guaranteed return ["normal" space](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Zs) separator hence your assertion should start working normally

Comment: Thanks Dmitri.  That worked.  I appreciate your expertise.